# Swift 3 - Error 'Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal'

Tags: ios, json, swift, geojson

I have downloaded the 'GeoJSON' pod via Cocoapods. But when I try to run my app I recieve following error.

**Error**: Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal. [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKE1X.png)

```
public var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "geometry": [
                "coordinates": self.geometryCoordinates,
                "type": type(of: self).type
            ],
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": [:]
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
public var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "geometry": [
                "coordinates": self.geometryCoordinates,
                "type": Self.type
            ] as [String: Any],
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": [:]
        ]
    }
```